# WrapContent around layout elements not bg

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I'm designing a regular android `LinearLayout` which consists of a punch of elements, I set layout parameters both to `wrap_content` and that makes it wraps around either **bg** or **elements** according to which one is bigger, So, how to assign the layout so that it wraps around it's elements whatever which is bigger(bg/elements)?

**for ex:**

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/overlay">

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want it to wrap around `name` whatever it's more big or `overlay` is bigger.

**example images:**

- what I have with big backgrounds assigned to a layout:

[image]

- what I try to reach:

[image]

Comment: show screenshot. Its a bit unclear. Show xml, too.

Comment: @MysticMagic I just didn't want to personalize the problem as I believe it's a general case

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi that's what I wan to work around it

Comment: @MysticMagic anyhow I added an example of what I mean, kindly consider having a look at it.

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi I added an example of what I mean, kindly consider having a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/overlay">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

with

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/overlay" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So background would be applied to `TextView` only. Anyhow, `LinearLayout` is of width wrap_content, so it will be fine.

Comment: that makes the same, wraps the TextView around it's own big background(overlay) which leads to that same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's idea of doing tht..

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:background="#ffffff" 
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Main line is... `android:layout_margin="3dp"` that gives you margin from all side as much you want..
Put right answer if its worthy to you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:background="#FF4081"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="this is text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#C3C3C3">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```